# Low validation accuracy, with high trining accuracy in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I built a Keras model (CapsNet model) on a dataset of over 300,000 images, with 80% for training and 20% for testing. The problem I'm having now is that the model has a high training accuracy of 96% and a low validation accuracy of 29%.

**My dataset contains 3 classes and it's distributed like this:**

Number of **trining** images: **271941**
The **percentage** of occurrences of each class: **[39% 39% 21%]**

Number of **testing** images: 68073

The **percentage** of occurrences of each class: **[41% 37% 21% ]**

Model Code:

```
def train(model, data, args):

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = data

# callbacks
log = callbacks.CSVLogger(args.save_dir + '/log.csv')
tb = callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=args.save_dir + '/tensorboard-logs',
                          histogram_freq=int(args.debug))

checkpoint = callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(args.save_dir + '/weights-{epoch:02d}.h5', monitor='val_capsnet_accuracy',
                                       save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True, verbose=1)
lr_decay = callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(schedule=lambda epoch: args.lr * (args.lr_decay ** epoch))

# compile the model
model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=args.lr),
              loss=[margin_loss, 'mse'],
              loss_weights=[1., args.lam_recon],
              metrics={'capsnet': 'accuracy'})

# to interrupt training when the validation loss isn't decreasing anymore
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2)

model.fit([x_train, y_train], [y_train, x_train], batch_size=args.batch_size, epochs=args.epochs,validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[early_stopping,log, tb, checkpoint, lr_decay])
return model
```

I set 50 epochs, but using the early stopping function, the model stopped on the third epoch with a validation accuracy of 29%.

Comment: What is your question? Why is this happening? How to improve your validation accuracy? Is the code correct?

Comment: @Chaos_Is_Harmony yes the code is correct, my question is why the validation accuracy is very low?

Comment: Did you try removing the early stopping, did the validation accuracy increase ?